# Swap() func in the book Essential C does not compile

Tags: c, pointers, specifier

wtf.c:11:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token
Swap(&a, &b);

wtf.c:11:10: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token
 Swap(&a, &b);

Did not want to resort to StackOverflow for my personal problem but i cannot figure it out. The code is exactly the same as the book's. I've also tried making separated pointers and using them as arguments but i get the same error. Can someone shine some light on what am i doing wrong? I'm using gcc to compile the code.

```
static void Swap(int *x, int *y){
  int temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

int a = 1;
int b = 2;

Swap(&a, &b);
```

I expected it to compile at least the exact example from the book but apparently not even that's possible.

Comment: nice file name. is this the exact code, without main function etc.? if you copy pasted the whole file, it might have been more helpful

Comment: You need a `main`  function, you can not call `Swap` in global scope.

Comment: Thank you guys and yes, this is the exact copy. The example is devoid of a main() function and it is not specified anywhere that i should be using it to call functions, at least not as far as i am in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void Swap(int *x, int *y){
  int temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;

  Swap(&a, &b);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

That compile and the execution print "2 1", as you can see *swap* works

---

You had the compiler errors because of the form `Swap(&a, &b);` which is not a declaration nor a definition (it is a function call)

As it is said in remark the entry point of any C program is the function *main*, automatically called, for more read documentation about C

Comment: This has in fact worked. I wonder why this was not specified in the book...

Comment: @spaghettiBox: Usually, you see the function definition, followed by text that says something like *"You use this function thus:"*, and then the usage example. The idea is that the function definition is the code you add to your own program or library, and the use example shows how you *can* use it. It is not intended to be a self-contained example *program*.  If you want a self-contained example program from such examples, you do exactly what bruno did here. So, you can think of this approach as shorthand; omitting the always-same "red tape".

Comment: Nominal Animal very well said, i'm simply used to being held by my hand and walked through the steps. I will look at this book differently henceforth.